# AJAX: live function trouble

Tags: javascript, ajax, events

i'm trying to do a shopping cart animation with jquery, to do that i've a script that on the mouseover event load a div :

```
$('#cart > .heading a').live('mouseover',function() {
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
    $('#cart').addClass('active');  
});
$('#cart').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#cart').removeClass('active');
});
```

but the problem is that with the "live" function the tag  does'nt work anymore.

Comment: What's your version of jQuery ? `live` has been removed from last ones.

Comment: the on and live function have the same effect,i've red that the "on" function is more efficient, but i've the same problem with the <a href=..">  i'll show u the html code :
<div id="cart">
 <div class="heading">
  <h4><img src="cart-bg.png"></h4>
  <a href="<?php echo $cart;?>" >...</a></div>
  <div class="content" id="cartnew">
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Maybe it's hard to answer the question because it's not clear. What do you mean with "the tag does'nt work anymore" ?

Comment: that does'nt redirect me to the page pointed by the href attribute, if  i remove the js code, it works

Answer (score 1):

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been replaced by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Deprecated: 1.7, Removed: 1.9

Try an event delegated approach:

```
$('#cart').on('mouseover','.heading a',function() {
//etc
```

Comment: thx for the answers, i've tried to replace the live with the on function as you suggest , but i still have the same problem with the <a> that does'nt redirect me correctly,

Comment: @user2021298 well, `load()` doesn't redirect the user. Are you looking  for `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('#cart > .heading a').on('mouseover',function() {
  $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
  $('#cart').addClass('active');  
});
$('#cart').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#cart').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: No. If you want to use event delegation with `on()`, pass 3 arguments.